# Two consecutive gacutil commands, within 15 sec. of each other:

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, com, interop, assemblies

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil.
exe /i "C:\Users\wherever\ClassLibrary1.dll"
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Assembly successfully added to the cache

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil.
exe /uf "ClassLibrary1.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

No assemblies found matching: ClassLibrary1.dll
Number of assemblies uninstalled = 0
Number of failures = 0

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>
```

I can see "ClassLibrary1.dll" is in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ClassLibrary1\v4.0_1.0.0.0__2efc1c0b243a0c09.  Did gacutil.exe ever install this thing in the first place?  Can it not uninstall it?  Can it see what it just informed me it installed?  Is it designed to install or uninstall .NET 4 assemblies?

Comment: Looks like you have to delete redundant quote mark. /uf "ClassLibrary1.dll -> /uf ClassLibrary1.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking the .dll off the assembly name in the second command.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools>gacutil.
exe /uf ClassLibrary1
```

Per the doc, the gacutil /u command is asking for an assembly name, not a path or file name. 
I tried this with .dll at the end on one of my assemblies and got the same error you did.

Can't promise this is right, but it's what I see.

Also worth noting, a gacutil /u or /uf can remove multiple versions of an assembly at once. So it is worth specifying version if you don't want to remove them all.

Comment: Thanks for your last para too.